# If the euclidean algorithm is used to solve an equation ( i.e., $ax = b \mod(z)$) is the solution unique?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

I have solved such an equation using the euclidean algorithm. However, unlike other methods, this gives one solution. Is this just one solution or the only solution.

Help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean unique modulo $z$ or unique for all integers? Obviously adding a multiple of $z$ would give another solution.

Comment: Unique modulo z.

Comment: You need gcd(a,b,z) =1 to have a chance of uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

No. For instance, if you consider the equation
$$ 3x \equiv 6 \pmod{9},$$
then there are the three incongruent solutions $2, 5, 8 \pmod 9$. But the Euclidean Algorithm will only ever give you one congruence class of solutions. However, if $\gcd(a,z) = 1$ in $ax \equiv b \pmod z$, then the solution from the Euclidean Algorithm is the only solution.